# do bitbucket pipeline steps have to be sequential?

Tags: git, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have set up multiple steps with manual triggers in pipelines. It will only allow me to trigger the first step. Is this because I need to trigger all preceding steps to run a given step? Is there a way around this? To setup multiple manual steps I can trigger whenever I want regardless of their order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you can use custom pipelines, that are always manually triggered.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html?&_ga=2.23648634.1733598165.1526225429-1865898393.1499075615#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_customcustom(optional)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question!

Comment: Well the answer is yes they do and the only way around them is by configuring custom pipelines!

Comment: Then this should be in the answer body.